# How to replicate the "popup" messages seen in SE sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net

StackOverflow and other sites in the SE Network have nifty things that pop up with messages, for example, when you click on an upvote link while not logged in. I'm not sure what this sort of thing is called, though.

I'm assuming that this is done with CSS somewhere, but looking at the source of the pages with a view to reverse engineering it, it doesn't seem like the buttons are actually links.

Using C# and ASP.NET, how could I emulate this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches available to accomplish those kinds of requirements.

You can use `JavaScript` / `jQuery` or `Ajax`

For example, have a look at these articles

[jQuery Popup](http://www.jquerypopup.com/)

[JavaScript Popup Windows](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml)

[Ajax ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is the ModalPopupExtenders and such found in the AjaxControlToolkit. Plenty to learn, and too much to really put in one answer. Quick example to see if this is in the right direction, http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

They are pretty customizable and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use standalone plugin, like [Noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/), jGrowl or Notifica.